# Creating Un-Sort data generation algorithm for a game

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Imagine there's a game where players are given blocks of colors.

Every block contains 6 colors.

```
Block = [Red,Red,Red,Red,Red,Red]
```

The goal is to generate an algorithm that generates blocks that require sorting.

For instance

```
Block1 = [Red,Red,Red,Blue,Blue,Blue]
Block2 = [Yellow,Yellow,Yellow,Yellow,Blue,Blue]
Block3 = [Blue, Blue, Blue, Blue, Yellow, Yellow]
Block4 = [Blue, Blue, Blue, Red, Red, Red]
```

The above is valid because we can sort the above to ensure all blocks have a single color !

```
Block1 = [Red * 6]
Block2 = [Yellow* 6]
Block3 = [Blue* 6]
Block4 = [Blue* 6]
```

The goal here is to create an algorithm (in C# but could be any language) that is able to create a bit list of unsorted blocks to be sorted, respecting the rules of they always should match at the end.

This is something simillar done in games
like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPwCq7inbT4&t=201s

Any ideas of known algorithms that can be used ?

Also any ideas of how to steadly increase difficulty as more and more blocks are generated ? (so they are more "split" than others, so initial blocks might have two colors, later on maybe three or four)

Comment: Most languages have some kind of random `shuffle` available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: The idea in the comments above is - start with a pre-sorted set then shuffle it.  For the blooms game you linked to, they might create the full set offscreen then dole them out one by one.  For the difficulty, you might permute / shuffle subsets - shuffle in groups of 2-4, groups of 4-6, 6-8, ...

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as

- add the color possibilities to some collection, filling enough to make each block
- shuffle the collection
- slice collection as blocks